# Prestashop: How to change base URL to https?

Tags: url, prestashop, radix

is there any way to change the PrestaShop base URL to https? At the moment my base URL is: http://www.kunst-in-bildern.de/

The problem is, my SSL is not working properly like this. The browser shows an insecure connection due to mixed content (http and https). When I use sslcheck it shows me the following:

[image]

So, I would like to get rid of the http-links by changing the base ULR to https
Thanks for tips on how to do that
Fabian

Comment: you need to search in your theme, modules and cofigurations where does entries are set and change them to https. they could be hardcoded in your theme, or referenced in you cms pages, etc...

Comment: Thanks a lot @sadlyblue. I was afraid of that :(
Now I have to find all the exact links in my thrid party theme :( :(

Is there any tip for finding specific links faster? E.g. I have no idea where to change this one: http://www.kunst-in-bildern.de/img/cms/headr-bg-catalog.jpg

Could firebug help in any way? I can find only css sources there but no hints for html source files.

Answer (score 0):

I always solved these issues manually thanks to https://www.whynopadlock.com/ which tells you exactly where is the content delivered without https. It's enough for you to manually change the link from http:// to https://

Otherwise, I recently dicovered an integrated functionality in Cloudflare which does the same thing automatically.

As stated on Cloudflare

"Automatic HTTPS Rewrites helps fix mixed content by changing "http" to "https" for all resources or links on your web site that can be served with HTTPS."

You can find this function under the "Crypto" menu once you have registered and validated you website with their service which is totally free.

If you don't want or can't use Cloudflare, I believe that the only option is to do it manually because if the http links are hard coded in your theme, they will remain the same even if you find a way to change the base URL.

Probably all the links that you can't find easily are in the TPL files related to where the mixed content is.

Have a nice day,

Vlad